# How to do basic http in IOS

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, httpwebrequest

I want to incorporate a basic HTTP protocol to allow syncing with a back-end database for the users of my iPad app. I don't intend to stream audio or video, I just want to access a server and do some low volume HTTP Gets and Puts. I don't see any IOS support for HTTP other than streaming.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly you can use HTTP for XML, JSON services, etc. Look at `NSURLConnection` http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Direct quote form there website:

[What is ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)?
ASIHTTPRequest is an easy to use wrapper around the CFNetwork API that makes some of the more tedious aspects of communicating with web servers easier. It is written in Objective-C and works in both Mac OS X and iPhone applications.

It is suitable performing basic HTTP requests and interacting with REST-based services (GET / POST / PUT / DELETE). The included ASIFormDataRequest subclass makes it easy to submit POST data and files using multipart/form-data.