# Web Portals vs Mobile Application Development

Tags: android, ios, gps

I am working to create a web portal using a closed network.  We are using GPS to map people's movement with hardware devices.  We do not want to use cellular connections and want to keep it in a closed network.

We are going to use a back end database that connects the devices to a tracking system and aggregates all the GPS locations to show on one GPS map.

This seems very simple in comparison to the use of a mobile application since everyone will be using their cell phones to monitor the device location pins.

What are some options for connecting the web portal to the database and filtering that information to the web portal?

Would a mobile application work better?

Comment: What actually want to do? You have tagged this question by two different mobile OS then asking **Would a mobile application work better?**

Comment: Couldn't tag it with anything else besides the suggested tags.  I want to connect a mobile capable GPS interface with a piece of hardware in the fitness industry.  Using a mobile app would be preferable but a web portal would be faster to bring to market.

Answer (score 2):

write web-services that will communicate between web-database and mobile apps. So mobile apps can post the GPS data (latitude,longitude) to the backend web database.
for communication from ioS apps, Refer: [How to do basic http in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668855/how-to-do-basic-http-in-ios)